# Pipes Angular 2: Sort Array of Objects

Tags: angular, angular2-template

There are similar questions but none of the answers have done the trick for me, so I would appreciate if you don't mark this as duplicate (unless you refer me to answer question that does solve the issue)

I have a Array of Objects `result:Array<Object>=[];` which is returned with these values:
[image: Array Object data]

On my template, I would like to sort the response based on count of 'likes'

```
<tr class *ngFor="let media of (result) | orderBy: 'data.likes.count'">
   <td>
     <img src={{media.data.images.standard_resolution.url}} height="100" width="100">
     <p> {{media.data.likes.count}} </p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The sort pipe looks like this:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'orderBy', pure: false})

export class SortPipe {

  transform(array: Array<Object>, args: string): Array<Object> {

    console.log("calling pipe");

    if (array == null) {
      return null;
    }

    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[args] < b[args] ){
        //a is the Object and args is the orderBy condition (data.likes.count in this case)
            return -1;
        }else if( a[args] > b[args] ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

When I run this code, it shows me an unordered response, rather then sorting it based on the likes. I should point that that when I do `console.log(a[args])` on the pipe I get undefined so I am probably not reading the value in the object field correctly.

Comment: does the response look like; 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2 etc.? Just because you didnt find a solution to your specific question, doesn't mean the other answers are wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I just meant that perhaps they weren't solving the issue I am facing. To answer your question, the response is unaffected by orderBy pipe

Comment: SO isn't here to solve your specific problem, even if it's related to others that might not work for you. But anyways, I'm too drunk to care currently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass args like that

Should be :

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.data.likes[args] < b.data.likes[args] ){
        //a is the Object and args is the orderBy condition (data.likes.count in this case)
            return -1;
        }else if( a.data.likes[args] > b.data.likes[args] ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

And then in your template :

```
<tr class *ngFor="let media of (result) | orderBy: 'count'">
```

---

And if you really want to do what you're doing ( I really discourage )  , you need to use a helper to parse your `data.likes.count` and return the deeper object.

```
function goDeep(obj, desc) {
    var arr = desc.split(".");
    while(arr.length && (obj = obj[arr.shift()]));
    return obj;
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            let aDeep = goDeep(a,args);
            let bDeep = goDeep(b,args);
            if (aDeep < bDeep ){
            //a is the Object and args is the orderBy condition (data.likes.count in this case)
                return -1;
            }else if( aDeep > bDeep ){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

And then you can use it like you wanted ;

```
<tr class *ngFor="let media of (result) | orderBy: 'data.likes.count'">
```

Comment: That works! But does that mean that I need to build a separate pipe for every such sorting. I need to implement other views for the same Object so wondering if there is a way to combine ?

Comment: I see - your second way actually answers my followup question. Why do you discourage that though? Performance issues?